# Wordpress Import of Media failing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am running two wordpress sites both on localhost from XAMPP/Apache
They are both in subdirs and work well and I am trying to transfer the content and media of one to the other, when I do it, it imports well except for the media which fails to import "Failed to import " gets spammed for almost every single image.

How do I resolve this? I honestly don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue was happening with me. It was resolved by itself after a 2 or 3 times retry.

Comment: I've done it several times, I don't see why that would change it.